# My fetched data only shows one data instead of showing two (Firebase, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview, fetch

I am fetching some details from firebase and showing them on `UITableView`.
Each row/cell is supposed to show 2 labels, however, it's showing just one.

My Main View Controller:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class NewFoodCaloriesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var addFood: DatabaseReference!

    @IBOutlet weak var txtNewFoodInsert: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtNewFoodCaloriesInsert: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblSuccess: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var tableFoodList: UITableView!
    var foodList = [FoodModel]()

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return foodList.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

        let food: FoodModel

        food = foodList[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblFoodType.text = food.foodname
        cell.lblFoodCalories.text = food.foodcalories
        //print("II")
        return cell

    }
```

My ViewControllerTableViewCell:

```
class ViewControllerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var lblFoodType: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblFoodCalories: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

My FoodModel.swift

```
{
    var foodid: String?
    var foodname: String?
    var foodcalories: String?
    var userid: String?

    init(foodid: String?, foodname: String?, foodcalories: String?, userid: String?)
    {
        self.foodid = foodid
        self.foodname = foodname
        self.foodcalories=foodcalories
        self.userid = userid
    }
}
```

the expected result is needed to show the Foodname and FoodCalories in the table view, but now it only shows the FoodName in the table view

Comment: How many elements are there in `foodList` array?

Comment: There could be a number of things wrong; I assume your table is showing the foodname and not the foodcalories? Or is it only showing one row? The problem description is a bit vague. You also need to include a snippet of your Firebase structure so we know what your data looks like and super important to include your Firebase code as that's likely where the issue is. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, most probably you are having the 2 labels vertically aligned and the bottom row gets cropped because the row height is less than the combined height of both the labels.

You can properly add constraints and use TableView automatic dimension or implement `heightForRow` delegate method as follow.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```